# revokeSignInSessions not revoking session cookies

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I haven't had any success revoking the B2C session cookies with /users/{id}/revokeSignInSessions endpoint.
I can see that it actually updates the "refreshTokensValidFromDateTime" property, so probably not a permission issue.
Rejecting refresh tokens from before that date in a custom policy during sign in has no effect. I guess the custom policy is not even being run because the session cookie is still valid.
It also seems not to have an effect in the default signin user flow.

It is an issue in particular in combination with Keep Me Signed In and revoking access globally (not only in the current browser, so calling /logout endpoint not an option).
Lowering access token or cookie lifetime, or changing SingleSignOn Scope attribute is not an option. Changing the user's password does not invalidate the cookie either.
Only way to invalidate the cookies seems to be to set Scope=Policy and forcing that user to a different policy or disabling the user. Then leave it like that until cookie expires (after days specified in SingleSignOn KeepAliveInDays attribute).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Thanks @Mortem. Yes and this is expected and refresh tokens are revoked and its explained in the document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-revokesigninsessions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: But according to the documentation you are linking to, it is supposed to also invalidate the cookie: "(as well as session cookies in a user's browser)".
So if that is not the case, there is no way to revoke the session cookies (than e.g. disabling the user, as I wrote)?

Comment: The integration of Microsoft Graph with B2C is limited. `revokeSignInSessions` should not apply to invalidating B2C session cookie. If you need this, you can [post a B2C user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/category/160596-b2c).

Comment: @Allen According to their documentation it is supposed to invalidate session cookies (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-revokesigninsessions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), but I was told on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/294953/revokesigninsessions-not-revoking-session-cookies.html that it was a mistake and that they would fix the documentation. Apparently the documentation was updated the same day as promised, but it still states that session cookies are invalidated